# How to sanitize array values in mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, sanitize

I have the following schema:

```
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({

}, {strict: "throw"});

adSchema.add({
   files: {
    type: [String] // ^\d{1,2}:[\w-]{7,14}$/
   }
});
```

When new model get saved to mongodb database I need to sanitize files field to be only values that correspond to `^\d{1,2}:[\w-]{7,14}$/` and drop other that don't.

What is the base place to sanitize?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [match validator](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_string_SchemaString-match)

Comment: Yes I've seen validators but I can't use them because they throw error on negative case but I need to drop value and continue

Comment: @Erik: ever thought about catching said error?